# using a string of values in WHERE clause - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string of values like :

```
$cat = "1,5,6,8,9";
```

now I would like to use that variable in WHERE clause. how do I do it ?

```
"select category from test where category...?"
```

I am using below code but I get null from number_of_result variable :

```
$array_of_cat = explode(",",$cat);

if($number_of_result == 0){
    $mresult = mysql_query("select * from books where
     GoodName like '%$title%' and GroupCode in ($array_of_cat) ");
    $number_of_result = mysql_num_rows($mresult);
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking `$number_of_result` before the query? `$number_of_result` isn't set yet.

Comment: $number_of_result will be sent from phone devices.

Comment: Here is [the fundamental problem](http://ideone.com/KCrVWZ) reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL statement to this one. Use `implode()` to pass array elements in `IN` clause

```
$mresult = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM books 
  WHERE GoodName LIKE '%$title%' AND GroupCode IN (" . implode(",", $array_of_cat) . ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to explode the variable - doing so results in an array that will result in the wrong value (the string "Array") when interpolated into the SQL string.

Despite the fact that this is unsafe ([SQL injection prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) you could do:

```
if($number_of_result == 0){
    $mresult = mysql_query("select * from books where
     GoodName like '%$title%' and GroupCode in ($cat)");
    $number_of_result = mysql_num_rows($mresult);
}
```

I strongly suggest you use the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function to prepare your variables.

Comment: It is time to update suggestions. `mysql_` is *deprecated* and should *not* be recommend at all.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Half the apps that use `mysql` and `php` use them though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat = array(1,5,6,8,9);

$array_of_cat = implode(",",$cat);

if($number_of_result > 0){
  $mresult = mysql_query("select * from books where
  GoodName like '%$title%' and GroupCode in ($array_of_cat) ");

$number_of_result = mysql_num_rows($mresult);
}
```

Also, I'd strongly suggest reading up on [PDO](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.pdo.php&ei=AX0BVNmcE4Kt0QW114GgAg&usg=AFQjCNFIwSE1mNG_k_lj0510AL_SsZs5Vg&bvm=bv.74115972,d.d2k)/[MySQLi](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.mysqli.php&ei=E30BVI33KqSP0AWPnoD4DA&usg=AFQjCNEqr4MIMr-la3jWWjZ1PQbJFnyFHw&bvm=bv.74115972,d.d2k)